# Issue with Product Flat

Tags: magento-1.9, php

The issue happen when i enable the flat product, and i need this feature to reduce the load/response time.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat::getEntityTablePrefix() in /home/*****/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php on line 507
```

Comment: Have you cleared your cache and re-indexed?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the failure is at this line:

```
$entityTable  = array($this->getEntity()->getEntityTablePrefix(), $this->getBackendType());
```

I'm not sure if that is much help, but perhaps this page will be:

http://alanstorm.com/magento_advanced_orm_entity_attribute_value_part_1